# Insert a varchar column value into another varchar column after few desired words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named ClinicalDocuments which has a column named vReportText and it saves soap text of a lot of components. Now there is another table named TreatmentOrders with a column vSoapText which contains the soap text of order component.

I want to write a SP which will update soap text of order component in ReportText of clinical documents just after heading of Treatment Order is. I know it will involve some string manupulation to determine the exact position after heading to insert value but i can't figure out how exactly it is possible.

here is what vReportText's sample data is

```
<table class="tblButton" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <font id="Comp_Heading" class="Comp_Heading" face="arial">&lt;&lt; MD Notes &gt;&gt;</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="traDetail" class="traDetail">
                <td>
                    <label onkeydown="return stopDataEntry()" id="lbl" oncut="" vbscript:window.event.returnvalue="false"
                        ondrop="" vbscript:window.event.returnvalue="false" ondblclick="lblDbl_Click('btn~~52437s80')"
                        contenteditable="false" onpaste="" vbscript:window.event.returnvalue="false"
                        ondrag="" vbscript:window.event.returnvalue="false">
                        <font id="Comp_Heading_Detail" class="Comp_Heading_Detail" face="arial"></font>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

vSoapText column also contains a html script in string, now i want to insert vsoaptext column value in the font tag **Comp_Heading_Detail**.

Our application was built in classic asp of which i don't know much either so i thought if i could do this with some handy script, it will make my life easy. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Can you share some sample data? and you desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use option with [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) string function

Let's assume you have two tables with this schemas

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TreatmentOrders
 (
  Id int,
  vSoapText nvarchar(100)
  )

INSERT dbo.TreatmentOrders
VALUES(1, 'InsertedText1'),
      (2, 'InsertedText2')

CREATE TABLE dbo.ClinicalDocuments
 (
  Id int,
  TreatmentOrdersId int,  
  vReportText nvarchar(100)
  )

INSERT dbo.ClinicalDocuments
VALUES(1, 1, '123 Treatment Order is 123'),
      (2, 1, '12345 Treatment Order is 123'), 
      (3, 2, '123 Treatment Order is 123'),
      (4, 2, '12345 Treatment Order is 123')

UPDATE d
SET d.vReportText = 
  REPLACE(vReportText,'Treatment Order is','Treatment Order is ' + o.vSoapText)
FROM dbo.ClinicalDocuments d 
  JOIN dbo.TreatmentOrders o ON d.TreatmentOrdersId = o.Id
```

Before

```
Id  TreatmentOrdersId vReportText
1   1                 123 Treatment Order is 123
2   1                 12345 Treatment Order is 123
3   2                 123 Treatment Order is 123
4   2                 12345 Treatment Order is 123
```

After

```
Id  TreatmentOrdersId vReportText   
1   1                 123 Treatment Order is InsertedText1 123
2   1                 12345 Treatment Order is InsertedText1 123
3   2                 123 Treatment Order is InsertedText2 123
4   2                 12345 Treatment Order is InsertedText2 123
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a47d/1)

For update location of text "Comp_Heading_Detail" use this

```
UPDATE d
SET d.vReportText =
  REPLACE(vReportText, 'font id="Comp_Heading_Detail"', 'font id="' + o.vSoapText+ '"')
FROM dbo.ClinicalDocuments d 
  JOIN dbo.TreatmentOrders o ON d.TreatmentOrdersId = o.Id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Can you look at the sample data my vReportText column contains and see if i can find the exact location of text "Comp_Heading_Detail" so that i may update vSoapText value onwards?

Comment: @WaseemSarwar Answer updated. FYI, best way to storing data of xml is XML data type, not a string.

Comment: i will try this to see if it solves mine issue. Thanks a lot for your advice and if i was designing this batabase, i would have gone for XML data type but its almost a decade old DB and code which i am mainting.